# Component re-rendering on Private Route in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have created a Private Route for my Application. So once the user is logged In, then he can navigate through all the pages from the SideMenu.
The problem here is each time when a link is clicked the SideMenu Component is re-rendered causing a performance issue.
The links in the SideMenu is wrapped around using Link

Here is my component Structure:

**App.js**

```
<Router>
<PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Layout} />
<PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Layout} />
<PrivateRoute path="/contact" component={Layout} />
<Route path="/login" component={Login} />
</Router>
```

**Layout.js**

```
<div>
<SideMenu />
 <Switch>
  <Route exact path="/dashboard">
   <Dashboard />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/contact">
   <Contact />
  </Route>
</Switch>
</div>
```

**PrivateRoute.js**

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    localStorage.getItem('user')
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location }}} />
  )} />
)
```

Comment: Is there any reason why u need to define routes that were defined in App.js into Layout.js as well?
You have redefined contact and dashboard inside Layout.js which is not required and causing re-renders.
This way Sidebar can simply redirect to particular page

Comment: Yes, I have been trying to implement the Private routing for my dashboard. But in App.js by removing other Routes, it was not navigating, So had to add in App.js

Comment: This shouldn't be the case,But can you host your code on codesandbox?

Comment: @PRATIKNAIK Can you share a sandbox with Protected Routes implemented ? That will help me implement the same thing in my project.

Comment: @PRATIKNAIK I have added my code in the codesandbox here. https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-login-auth-forked-h5g6n?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the code within App.js

```
<Router>
<PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Layout} />
<Route path="/login" component={Login} />
</Router>
```